# Drag and Drop list using jquery UI is not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery-ui

I am working with drag and drop list using jquery UI, it is working fine with Chrome but it seems not working with Firefox.

Here is the link:
http://embed.plnkr.co/WcIZlD/

Please help me on this.

Comment: check for errors in your console...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unable to reach your Plnkr. Please provide a more complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's Strange but it's not showing any error in console. #karthik

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Please change your code.

Current Code:
`$(event.originalEvent.toElement)`

Change it to:
`$(event.originalEvent.target)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working. But could you please explain it. :-)

Comment: In firefox toElement is undefined. Whenever you drop any element to a target element you will receive the target element in target attribute. So I used target instead of toElement.